# Selenium Error: Element is not clickable at point(X,Y), other element would receive the click

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python and selenium. On [this](https://steemit.com/steem/@cheolwoo-kim/what-is-steemit) link I would to click `Reply` to add comment

> Element is not clickable at point (933.9500122070312,
>   16.666671752929688). Other element would receive the click: `<a href="/create_account"></a>`

Code given here:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from gensim.summarization import summarize

from selenium import webdriver

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep     
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    driver.get(url)
    sleep(4)
    f = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PostFull__reply')
    f.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    f.click()
```

**Update**

This is how it appears in Inspector:

[image]

Comment: which element you want to find? PostFull__reply is not on the page

Comment: @YuZhang Question updated with image

Comment: did you log into your account?

Comment: Yes. And BTW, the link appears if you are not logged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css is correct, the problem with the long content is that it scrolls the element to below of the `.Header` that why it can't click the element.

You can get the location of the element and scroll to 100px less than Y coordinate since the height of `.Header` is 49.5px and it is better to maximize the window before testing. See below:

```
driver.maximize_window()
f = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PostFull__reply')
location = f.location["y"] - 100
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d);" %location)
f.click()
```

Comment: I am already using visible FireFox so guess no need of screenshot. The required CSS is not working across site. If a post have lots of text then it does not work. No Popup is there, however elements are being generated via JS

Comment: It works on random post. Try this and it will no work: https://steemit.com/steem/@bloggersclub/projects-corner-session-1-25-7-16-steem-your-way-to-crowdfunding-or-make-money-trying-upvoting-is-steem

Comment: @Volatil3 check my updated answer, for long content page it scrolls it to under the `.Header` that's why cant interact with it.

Comment: Superb. Can you please explain how are you figuring out `.Header`?

Comment: If you take screenshot when fail it you can see that there is no "replay" button because the header cover it. `find_element_by_css_selector ` function starts the index from 0.

Comment: Gotcha, but that `100`, is it fixed displacement every time?

Comment: @Volatil3 in your case it should be greater than 49,5 and not be greater than screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to click on `span` element while actually it should be `a` element. Here you should try to locate `a` element using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and clickable on `DOM` then perform click as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(url)

f = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".PostFull__reply > a")))
f.location_once_scrolled_into_view
f.click()
```

If unfortunately `f.click()` does not work correctly, you can also perform click using `execute_script()` as below :-

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', f)
```

Hope it works..:)