# Python Selenium:: Element is Currently Invisible

Tags: python, selenium

So I am accessing [this](https://steemit.com/steem/@ozchartart/usdsteem-btc-technical-analysis-2-the-only-way-for-me-to-move-on-is-to-chart-it-in-the-dawn) link and with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632255/275002) friend, I am able to progress a bit. Now I am stuck. The issue is, when someone clicks on `Reply` and click `Post` button it says `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

Code is given below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from gensim.summarization import summarize

from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import sys
import os
import xmltodict
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import traceback
import random

driver = None
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
        url = 'https://steemit.com/steem/@ozchartart/usdsteem-btc-technical-analysis-2-the-only-way-for-me-to-move-on-is-to-chart-it-in-the-dawn'

        driver.get(url)
        sleep(5)
        f = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PostFull__reply')
        location = f.location["y"] - 100
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d);" % location)
        f.click()
        t = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('textarea')
        b = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
        # b = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "button"))
        # )
        # print(b)
        t.click()
        sleep(1)
        t.send_keys('awesome!!')
        sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1",b)

        driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();')
        #if b.is_displayed():
        b.click()
    except Exception as e:
        driver.save_screenshot('myscreen.png')
        print(str(e))
```

Comment: I found this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: @grooveplex If you see, I already used it but did not work

Comment: have you tried to hover and click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're trying to interract with another button. Try more specific selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Post"]').click()
```

This works for me